# How to call a name from a dictionary in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, call

Say that I have the following dictionary:

```
mydict = {"3322": 4 , "3323": 3 , "3324": 5}
```

Now say that I want to print "3323" once the the user inputs 3.
What I've got so far:

```
printer = input("please enter a number: ")
```

Now i'm not sure how to use "printer" to print 3323 once the user inputs 3.

Comment: You want to look up a key for a matching value. What happens if there are multiple keys with the same matching value? What happens if there are none?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for **keys** (which must be *unique*) by their corresponding **values** (that can be repeated more than once in a dictionary,) it is possible for there to be more than one resulting key that maps to a given value.

Fortunately, we can find all of the keys using a list comprehension:

```
results = [k for k,v in mydict.items() if v == int(printer)]
```

And of course you can print them all out like so:

```
print('\n'.join(results))
```

This way, all of the keys found will be printed (separated by newlines,) and nothing will be printed if nothing is found.

Answer (score 0):

First your dictionary is "backwards", ie what you want to use a key is actually stored a value, flip it around with a dictionary comprehension:

```
mydict = {v:k for (k,v) in mydict.iteritems()}
```

Then it is best to capture user input in a while loop:

```
while 1:
    key = input("please enter a number: ")
    try:
        if int(key) in mydict:
            print mydict[int(key)]
            break
        else:
            print "{n} not present!".format(n = key)
    except ValueError:
        print "please enter a number!"
```

This way if the user messes up they can try again..

Comment: This is correct for Python 2. You would have to make a few minor changes so that it would work on Python 3. Also, this assumes that that no values are repeated.